# MySQL - OUTFILE in chrooted environment

Tags: mysql, csv, into-outfile

I want to export some data on a remote server mysql which then should be loaded to the client's mysql.
Because of huge amount of data, I try to use `INTO OUTFILE` to speed things up.

I try to export data of 20GB table into a csv / tsv file via `OUTFILE`:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE "test.csv" FROM myTable
```

I am in a chrooted environement, but somehow mysql does create the file **outside** the chrooted environment in the `/var/lib/mysql/myTable/test.csv` folder.

If I now try to copy that exported csv file to the client via scp nothing works, because the file is not within the chrooted environment (instead it is in the "real /var/lib/mysql/myTable"-folder):
`scp user@server:/var/lib/mysql/myTable/test.csv ./test.csv`

For gods sake, why is MySQL such a pain with large data sets? I guess there is no way to get the stuff in the right folder, f.e. `/var/www/vhosts/my-chrooted-environment/my-folder/test.csv` (mysql can't write to another folder, even `secure_file_priv` is disabled) due to permission problems. And this is happening even if the destination folder has chmoded to `777`...

Is there any way to get a fast csv/tsv output without INTO OUTFILE statement?

Comment: This link may be helpful for your purposes.  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/pdf/mysql-database-export.pdf